# Problema elemento "ErrorViewer:ctlError"

Tags: genexus

estou com problema com o elemento "ErrorViewer:ctlError" utilizando em uma transaction, quando executo a operação de deletar um objeto da base de dados a msg de confirmação da exclusão se duplica, quando atualizo a pagina a mensagem duplicada é corrigida, alguém sabe oque pode esta ocorrendo ?

Obs: foi aplicado na transaction o pattern

[image: Problema apresentado.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isso foi corrigido no Upgrade 3 da versão X Evolution 3. 
Referência: [SAC #36319](http://www2.gxtechnical.com/portal/hgxpp001.aspx?15,4,61,O,S,0,,36319)

Comment: Pablo, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Paulo, geralmente o Gx exibe essas mensagens em modo de exclusão de acordo com as propriedades confirm transaction e confirmation

experimente mudar a propriedade confirmation para "never prompt"
segue links de referência sobre as propriedades citadas acima:

http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Confirmation+property,
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?Confirm+Transactions+property

Espero que minha dica lhe ajude, senão for nenhum dos itens citados pode ser algum tipo de erro javascript decorrente da versão do genexus que esta utilizando, se puder informa-la posso fazer uma simulação para ver se o mesmo erro ocorre comigo e estudar outras formas de resolve-lo.

Atenciosamente, Felipe.

Comment: Felipe, fiz as configurações recomendadas mais o problema ainda persiste.
Foi possivel perceber que a falha so ocorre quando tento efetuar a exclusão
de algum objeto que não foi utlizado em alguma movimentação.

Quando solicito a exclusão de algum objeto que houve movimentação a msg
apresentada não ocorre a duplicação sendo exibida de forma correta.

`"Eliminação inválida, existe informação em Saida"``

A versão utilizada é EV3 - V 10.3.87933 U2